# Python :Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Tags: python, segmentation-fault

I'm a newbie, for my following code:

```
# Constant
c_dir = '/Users/sapfinance/PycharmProjects/RFBIBL00'
C_FILE_SEP = '|'
Fichier1 = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir=c_dir)
Fichier2 = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir=c_dir)
```

When I launch my report, if Fichier1 is a large file (higher than 300Mo Bytes) and Fichier2 is a tiny file, I have error message :
**Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)**
Otherwise, if the first file is the tiny and second is the large, there is no issue.

I'm using Python 3.11 in a MBP 2023.

The tiny file is located [here][1]
and large file, [here][2]

I add the log of error, why ?

````
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Python [75896]
Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            org.python.python
Version:               3.11.1 (3.11.1)
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        pycharm [49477]
Responsible:           pycharm [49477]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-02-13 17:42:44.2803 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 13.2 (22D49)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        CC935EEC-AECF-735E-06B3-40216C7B759F

Sleep/Wake UUID:       BE7F527D-88BD-4A69-8B1B-662C43878116

Time Awake Since Boot: 470000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       14851 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000001e
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000001e

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process:   exc handler [75896]

VM Region Info: 0x1e is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 105553518919650
     REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
     UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
     MALLOC_NANO (reserved)   600018000000-600020000000 [128.0M] rw-/rwx SM=NUL  ...(unallocated) ```


 [1]: https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZENVgVZpLLP9U5np7Vc9lxhOUJ3YyhhFCgk
 [2]: https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZrNVgVZ46GE8BQ24Y76ANlNSDHqhSio2dIy
````

Answer (score 0):

I have search into the web, bug is already known
https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/92603

Follow different reading, I solve the crash by adding:

```
root = tk.Tk()
```

There isn't anymore my crash.

I don't understand wy, my mind was to add a second instruction to destroy the windows, but it's working without.

So my new code is

```
from tkinter import filedialog
# Constant
c_dir = '/Users/sapfinance/PycharmProjects/RFBIBL00'
C_FILE_SEP = '|'
root = tk.Tk()
Fichier1 = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir=c_dir)

Fichier2 = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir=c_dir)
```